# Apache Ignite JMX Host not set?

Tags: heap-memory, ignite, jmx

I've setup an Ignite Server on a linux machine, that I'm configuring
and running over putty.

I wrote around 50.000 Key Value Pairs into the Heap.

But I´m not getting all the Data back?
Since I restarted the server, I'm getting this error:

```
bin/ignite.sh, WARN: Failed to resolve JMX host (JMX will be disabled): ignite-demo.novalocal
```

How can I resolve those problems?

Comment: Could you provide your cache configuration and code that you use to write/read values? Also what do you mean by writing into the heap?

Answer (score 0):

You can set JMX_PORT=some port value in environment variables. 
like,
JMX_PORT=8080

There are few solutions by gridgain experts like set IGNITE_JMX_PORT but it simply gives warning at start. See code in ignite.bat if you want to know more.